# Ruby: How does loading of objects in batches improve memory usage?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, performance

I'm self taught and not too sure about the terminology or specific improvements there are (if any) from splitting up object loading into separate parts in a loop.

For example, I use rails and recently I've encountered an issue where I was loading too many heavy ActiveRecord objects at once, and found this in the rails API: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Batches.html

What `find_in_batches` does is that it separates the query into many subsets so instead of making one large query, you're making 10 small ones and not loading so many objects at once.

Ex:

```
def batch_process
  Car.find_in_batches do |batch|
    batch.each(&:start_engine!)
  end # at the end of each iteration, is the memory from the current batch deallocated?
end

def start_all_at_once
  Car.all.each(&:start_engine!)
end
```

My question is, what exactly is the benefit of doing this? Conceptually I understand that loading less at once allows memory to be freed up on each loop (is this correct??), but what exactly is improved? I believe it's peak memory consumption, but does that translate to RAM / CPU usage improvements (not really sure what the difference between RAM / CPU is to be honest)? Or something to do with Garbage Collection or Ruby heap size?

Just trying to understand the lower level details. Thanks!

Comment: RAM = Memory; CPU = Processing power. This saves memory (RAM).

Comment: thanks! how is CPU ever saved then?

Comment: CPU is saved by making algorithms more efficient, minimizing the amount of calculating that needs to be done. Sometimes this is done by making sure large loops aren't unnecessarily recalculating things; and by storing intermediate values. Of course, sometimes CPU has to be increased rather than saved by distributing the load across many CPUS (via threads, job queues, multiple processes, etc)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's say you want to work on 1 million records in your database.

First, your database needs to load and send 1 million records to your Ruby application. Then Rails needs to parse those 1 million record (this uses memory) then generate 1 million record and a big array to contain the all. This will use lots of processing power (CPU) and memory (RAM) to store them all.

Let's say each record takes 1KB of memory (this is an arbitrary number). Then 1 million will take 1GB of memory, and we're not even counting what the memory used by the  database, the transfer and the transformations.

Now, load 1 million records in batches of a thousand. Then your database loads and transfers only 1000 records at once. Same for Ruby/Rails, and it will use 1MB of memory. Repeating for the next thousand records, will reuse that memory. Hence, you're only using a fraction of RAM of the previous example!

Comment: thanks! So is memory from each iteration freed / garbage collected / something else ??

Comment: It will be garbage collected. Running in batches will certainly use more memory than I described, since the GC may run after some loops, yet the memory can be reclaimed when necessary, so you never run out of it.